# What's the difference between int and C.int in go?

Tags: go, cgo

```
import "C"

func f() {
  var vGo int
  var vC  C.int
  // fails to compile with error
  // cannot use &vGo (type *int) as type *C.int in argument to...
  C.c_function(&vGo)  
  // compiles just fine:
  C.c_function(&vC)
}
```

I compile with CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH=arm...

What's the different in int and C.int types in this case?
Where do I find additional information on C types in GO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the difference between the types? It depends. If you're on 64bit, the Go int will be 64 bits while the C int will be 32. If you're on 32bit, there is no real difference.

Where do I find additional information on C types in Go? Look at documentation for C. As mentioned in the comments, implicit numeric type conversions aren't allowed in Go so a conversion is required.

Comment: Sorry, but the second part is not correct. Go `int` can be either 64 or 32 bit, depending on the architecture. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types

Comment: @jupp0r yes, I was trying to convey that with "if you're on 64bit" though my language was perhaps not specific enough.

Comment: The relevant difference isn't that they are 32 or 64 bits, it's that they are different types and Go doesn't allow implicit numeric type conversions. You will get the same error regardless of if the types are the same size or not.

Comment: JimB: that's not strictly true (see my answer for exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Go deliberately does not support implicit type conversion, with some exceptions[1](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") in any of these cases:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - T is an interface type and x implements T.
> - x is a bidirectional channel value, T is a channel type, x's type V and T have identical element types, and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

The conversion in your case is needed to match potentially different memory layouts[2](https://golang.org/src/cmd/cgo/gcc.go).